# Prove that $\arctan(\operatorname{arctanh}(x))\geq \operatorname{arctanh}(\arctan(x))$ for $0\leq x <1$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

It's inspired by a general result proposed in a book (Dictionary of inequalities second edition by Peter Bullen p.101) related to composition of  function :

In fact we have $x\in[0,1)$:

$$\arctan(\operatorname{arctanh}(x))\geq \operatorname{arctanh}(\arctan(x))\quad (1)$$

To prove it I have introduced a function :

$$f(x)=\arctan(\operatorname{arctanh}(x))-\operatorname{arctanh}(\arctan(x))$$

We differentiate to get:

$$f'(x)= -\frac{1}{((x^2-1)(\operatorname{arctanh}^2(x)+1))}+\frac{1}{((x^2+1)(\arctan^2(x)-1))}$$

And then I use :

Let $0\leq x <1$ then we have :

$$\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\geq x \geq \arctan(x)$$

Then I cannot conclude directly .

Question :

How to prove $(1)$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The hyperbolic reciprocal function is $\operatorname{argtanh}$.

Comment: @Bernard I use Geogebra in french so sorry for the confusion (if it is).

Comment: @Bernard I edit ?

Comment: I think you should. The name of the function is the same in French (formerly, it was argth).

Comment: @Bernard If we're being nitpicky, it's $\operatorname{artanh}$, actually. But I don't think it matters if people know what you mean.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: That's the ISO notation (for physicists). I don't like it, because much less meaningful than using arg. All the more so as the inverse trigonometric functions do use ‘arc’.

Comment: @Bernard It's "ar" because it comes from "area", in contrast to "arcus" for the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Well, I stick to ‘arg’ for ‘argument’ that I learnt  as a student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacLaurin expansion
$$\arctan\left(\operatorname{arctanh} x\right)=x+\frac{x^5}{15}+\frac{x^7}{45}+\frac{64 x^9}{2835}+\frac{71 x^{11}}{4725}+\frac{5209 x^{13}}{405405}+\frac{2203328 x^{15}}{212837625}+\ldots$$
All coefficients of the series are positive
$$\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\arctan x\right)=x+\frac{x^5}{15}-\frac{x^7}{45}+\frac{64 x^9}{2835}-\frac{71 x^{11}}{4725}+\frac{5209 x^{13}}{405405}-\frac{2203328 x^{15}}{212837625}+\ldots$$
Coefficients have the same absolute value as the previous series, but alternating signs from $5$th degree on.

Thus for $x\in[0,1)$
$$\arctan\left(\operatorname{arctanh} x\right)\ge \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\arctan x\right)$$
while for $x\in(-1,0]$ the opposite happens.

Comment: I don't think you can infer from a difference in a single term in MacLaurin expansion an inequality: you don't know what's in the respective $O(x^{11})$.

Comment: I have edited my answer @Bernard. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Quite clear, but it has to be proved, which mustn't be easy. I suppose you obtained this expansion with some software?

Comment: I don't expect that for the series it's cool (+1)

Comment: Use \operatorname instead of \text for functions :) \operatorname will add whitespace appropriately. I edited your answer accordingly. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for the tip!

Comment: The relation between the two Taylor series follows from the equality $\operatorname{atanh} (\arctan (ix)) = i\arctan (\operatorname{atanh} x)$. This equality can be shown as follows: $$
\operatorname{atanh} (\arctan (ix)) =\operatorname{atanh}(i\operatorname{atanh}x) =  - i\arctan (ii\operatorname{atanh} x) = i\arctan (\operatorname{atanh} x) .
$$ Here we used the relation $\operatorname{atanh} x=-i \arctan(ix)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Fact 1*: $\frac{-3x^3+12x}{-x^3-x^2+12x+12}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \ge \operatorname{arctanh}(x)$ for all $x \in [0, 1)$.
(Hint: Use $u^2 = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ and then take derivative.)

*Fact 2*: $\frac{64x^5+735x^3+945x}{225x^4+1050x^2+945} \ge \arctan x$ for all $x \in [0, 1)$.
(Hint: Take derivative.)

Let $f(x) = \arctan(\operatorname{arctanh}(x)) - \operatorname{arctanh}(\arctan(x))$.

By Facts 1-2, we have, for all $x$ in $[0, 1)$,
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{(1-x^2)(\operatorname{arctanh}^2(x)+1)} - \frac{1}{(x^2+1)(1 - \arctan^2(x))}\\
&\ge \frac{1}{(1-x^2)(\frac{(-3x^3+12x)^2}{(-x^3-x^2+12x+12)^2}\frac{1+x}{1-x}+1)} 
- \frac{1}{(x^2+1)(1 - (\frac{64x^5+735x^3+945x}{225x^4+1050x^2+945})^2)}\\
&\ge 0.
\end{align}
Also, $f(0) = 0$. Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $[0, 1)$.

We are done.